# MySql Strict Mode and cross database triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

There are two parts to this question,

1) Can i have one schema in strict mode and another in non-strict mode on the same MySql Database?

2) How can i write triggers which update table in another database. I cannot use Federated tables as I am not sure if federated tables generate bin logs, hence the replication issue.

Regards,

Ayush

Comment: With regard to your first question: `DBAs can set the global SQL mode to match site server operating requirements, and each application can set its session SQL mode to its own requirements.`, therefore, `Each client can change its session sql_mode value at any time.` See [5.1.7 Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html). With regard to your second question: Both databases or schemas, they are located in the same MySQL Server?

Comment: @wchiquito - for the second question, no they are not on the same server.

Comment: In that case, check: [17.4.1.32 Replication and Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-triggers.html).